# How do I use convertAndSendToUser() with an external broker such as RabbitMQ in Spring4?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-websocket

I am trying to configure web socket support in Spring 4 using RabbitMQ as the external broker, but as soon as I switch to RabbitMQ, I get the following error on start-up in the client:

```
'/user/queue/changes' is not a valid destination.
Valid destination types are: /temp-queue, /exchange, /topic, /queue, /amq/queue, /reply-queue/.
```

On the server I am using `convertAndSendToUser` and this works fine with the simple broker, but as soon as I switch to RabbitMQ, I get this error.  Note that RabbitMQ works fine for normal topic broadcasts - it's just the `/user` channel that falls over.

Do I need to do something special to get `/user` to work with RabbitMQ?

**Edit to include Web Socket Config**

My `WebSocketConfig` is pretty standard with a few customisations to integrate it with [spring-session](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html5/guides/websocket.html):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractSessionWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer<ExpiringSession> {


@Override
public void configureStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/changes").withSockJS();
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    //config.enableSimpleBroker("/queue", "/topic");
    StompBrokerRelayRegistration r = config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/user", "/topic");

    try {
        String rabbitUrl = System.getenv("CLOUDAMQP_URL");
        if(rabbitUrl != null) { 
            log.info("RABBIT URL detected: " + rabbitUrl);
            URI uri = new URI(rabbitUrl);
            String host = uri.getHost();                
            String login = uri.getUserInfo().split(":",2)[0];
            String passCode = uri.getUserInfo().split(":",2)[1];
            String vhost = uri.getPath().substring(1);
            r.setRelayHost(host);
            r.setSystemLogin(login);    
            r.setSystemPasscode(passCode);
            r.setClientLogin(login);    
            r.setClientPasscode(passCode);
            r.setVirtualHost(vhost);                
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        log.error("Error setting up RabbitMQ", e);
    }
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
  }
}
```

Comment: Who creates this /user/queue/channel channel? You need to create it before connecting.

Comment: Share you websocket config, please.

Comment: @mavarazy - I just call `convertAndSendToUser(userId, "/queue/loop-changes)` as per the docs and Spring automatically prepends `/user`.  Are you saying I need to create the `/user` destination in RabbitMQ somehow?

Comment: Yes, otherwise Rabbit won't work. There is a RabbitAdmin for that in spring

Comment: @mavarazy Thanks - I'm learning RabbitMQ as I go so this is all new to me.  There is nothing about this in the Spring Web Socket documentation unless I have missed something? Will I need to let rabbit know about the session stuff that Spring automatically appends to the destination to send it to a particular user?  And what is a "destination" in Rabbit?  From what I can tell, I can create queues, topics, channels and exchanges in Rabbit, but "destination" is related to STOMP, right?  I'm not sure how "destination" relates to RabbitMQ and how to set it up to send directly to a single user?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure on how Spring integrates with Rabbit. I would assume, that session translate to routing keys, so you would not have to worry about that. Regarding STOMP, in Rabbit it connects to the default topic, not sure how Spring interprites it.

Answer (score 2):

I met the similar error, but I didn't find an intuitive solution after searching Internet.

I would like to share my findings after going throught the doc of [RabbitMQ STOMP](http://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html).

According to the doc of [RabbitMQ STOMP](http://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html), only destination starting with `/exchange`, `/queue`, `/amq/queue`, `/topic` and `temp-queue` are allowed. The destination `/user/*` would NOT be allowed. You can choose the destination per the requirements of your message.

> /exchange -- SEND to arbitrary routing keys and SUBSCRIBE to arbitrary
>   binding patterns;
>
> /queue -- SEND and SUBSCRIBE to queues managed by the STOMP gateway;
>
> /amq/queue -- SEND and SUBSCRIBE to queues created outside the STOMP
>   gateway;
>
> /topic -- SEND and SUBSCRIBE to transient and durable topics;
>
> /temp-queue/ -- create temporary queues (in reply-to headers only).

For example, I would like to send a message to a topic to notify all subscribers.

> For simple topic destinations which deliver a copy of each message to
>   all active subscribers, destinations of the form **/topic/< name >** can be
>   used. Topic destinations support all the routing patterns of AMQP
>   topic exchanges.
>
> Messages sent to a topic destination that has no active subscribers
>   are simply discarded.
>
> AMQP 0-9-1 Semantics
>
> For SEND frames, the message is sent to the **amq.topic** exchange with
>   the routing key < name >.
>
> For SUBSCRIBE frames, an autodeleted, non-durable queue is created and
>   bound to the **amq.topic** exchange with routing key < name >. A
>   subscription is created against the queue.

The spec means that the stomp sub message with destination `/topic/<name>` will use the default exchange **amp.topic** of rabbitmq, then a binding might be created with the **variable name** if it does not exist and a queue also be created to bind the exchange **amp.topic** by that binding.

If you want to create a durable subscription, the client should send subscribe message with below headers.

```
durable:true
auto-delete:false
```

In my app the websocket server receives message `/watch/{liveid}`, then reply another message to topic `/topic/watchinfo-{liveid}`.

```
@Secured(User.ROLE_USER)
@MessageMapping("/watch/{liveid}")
@SendTo("/topic/watchinfo-{liveid}")
@JsonView(View.Live.class)
public LiveWatchInfoMessage liveinfo(@DestinationVariable("liveid") String liveid,
                                         @AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails activeUser) {
        ...
        return LiveWatchInfoMessage.builder().build();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `"/user"` from `config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/user", "/topic");`
and add the `"/queue"`, **spring automatically adds the `/user` when you `send-to-a-specific user`**

And just `sendTo(username, "/queue/(what_you_want)", msg)` and subscibe to `"/queue/(what_you_want)"`.

The bold statement came directly from RabbitMq website I tried to find the link but I got lazy

Comment: Thanks for explaining this in simplest form.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite an old question, but I just met the same error so my solution might works for others. It's basicly what @Memo 313 MediaSA said(and why his answer is downvoted).
The two key points I have found are:

1. set only the prefix that message broker support(for rabbitmq, see:https://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html), and only use them in application.
2. *optional: call setUserDestinationPrefix and set a user destinations for MessageBrokerRegistry when over configureMessageBroker.(the default is "/user/" so if you just want to use "/user/" as user destinations this setting is not necessary)

After doing those, everything should work as what doc for setUserDestinationPrefix methord says:

> For example when a user attempts to subscribe to "/user/queue/position-updates",
>   the destination may be translated to "/queue/position-updatesi9oqdfzo" yielding a
>   unique queue name that does not collide with any other user attempting to do the same.
>   Subsequently when messages are sent to "/user/{username}/queue/position-updates",
>   the destination is translated to "/queue/position-updatesi9oqdfzo".

Also, be sure that the {username} your application is using is the same with principal.

Comment: How did u handle the authentication through MQ?